# How i can change every index of array to lowercase and inside array to uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> [{        "abc": {            "xyz": {
>                 "jpy": {}   }}}]

Comment: You don't change an index of an array to lower-case, indices in JS arrays  are numbers.

Comment: But he have an object

Comment: Your example is incorrect.  "future" is in the wrong case

Comment: please do not change the question, because that invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a level count and take only the first level for lower case keys and all others for upper case keys.

```js
function change(object, level) {
    level = level + 1 || 0;
    if (!object) {
        return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.forEach(function (o) { change(o, level); });
        return;
    }
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var key = k[level === 1 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
        change(object[k], level);
        if (key !== k) {
            object[key] = object[k];
            delete object[k];
        }
    });
}

var array = [{ "BITFLYER": { "BTC": { "jpy": {} }, "ETH": { "BTC": {} }, "bch": { "BTC": {} }, "future": { "BTCJPY19JAN2018": {}, "BTCJPY26JAN2018": {} } } }, { "BITSTAMP": { "BTC": { "JPY": {} }, "ETH": { "BTC": {} }, "bch": { "BTC": {} } } }];

change(array);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like @NinaSholz's answer but uses some slightly different techniques.  Firstly, converting the entire array to uppercase string and then using `hasOwnProperty` to just convert the first level keys to lower case.

```js
    var array = [{ "BITFLYER": { "BTC": { "jpy": {} }, "ETH": { "BTC": {} }, "bch": { "BTC": {} }, "future": { "BTCJPY19JAN2018": {}, "BTCJPY26JAN2018": {} } } }, { "BITSTAMP": { "BTC": { "JPY": {} }, "ETH": { "BTC": {} }, "bch": { "BTC": {} } } } ];

    array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array).toUpperCase()).map( object => {
        var result = object;
        for (key of Object.keys(object)) {
            if (typeof key === "string" && object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                result = {};
                result[key.toLowerCase()] = object[key];
            }
        }
        return result;
    });
    console.log(array);
```